# Angular 10, how to access to <mat-select> value?

Tags: angular, viewchild

I'm trying to access to a  value I mean the current value of the select. I'm using a @ViewChild decorator, the object retrieved is huge and after search on it I can not find the value data. I´m using the local reference **#type** on  because placing it on  retrieves undefined.

```
<mat-form-field class="input-group">
      <mat-select #type placeholder="{{ 'request.detail.ticketTypes' | translate }}" 
         formControlName="ticketTypes" required>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let ticketType of ticketTypesQuery.list$ | async" 
           [value]="ticketType.id">
          {{ticketType.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Here the .ts file code

```
@ViewChild('type', {static: true}) typeSelect;

ngOnInit() {
console.log(this.typeSelect) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to do that. The selected value will be the actual value of the form control.

```
this.myFormName.controls['ticketTypes'].value;
```

Just correct myFormName with how your form is declared in .ts file

Answer (score 0):

In HTML you can add code as below

```
<mat-select [(value)]="dropownValue">

</mat-select>
```

When you change dropdown value it will be available in `dropownValue`.